# Azure encrypted blob download result is empty when downloading from different machine than the upload

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I've uploaded a text blob to azure storage (using UploadTextASync). Everything went OK, even downloading it again on the same workstation.
The problem is when I try downloading it from other server (stage):

- The call to blob.ExistsAsync reports the blob is there;
- **The call to blob.DownloadTextAsync returns an empty string**

*Setup:*

- the uploaded text is an html, UTF8 encoded;
- upload uses BlobRequestOptions with an IKey obtained from a  CachingKeyResolver which generates a secret key in the key vault;
- download uses BlobRequestOptions with a CachingKeyResolver which obtaines the same secret key

*Things checked so far:*

- blob connection strings are the same between local and the stage server;
- key vault name, client id, client secret and blob url are all the same between local and the stage server;
- Updated WindowsAzure.Storage to the latest version (7.2.1) even the old one used (6.2.0) was behaving the same;
- encryption mechanism is being successfully used in the same project (to upload/download octet streams); the only difference is in the method used

*Recap:*

- DownloadText (and its async method) returns empty string when called from a different machine

Code:

```
 public async Task<bool> UploadTextAsync(UploadTextBlobParameter parameter)
    {
        var container = await EnsureBlobContainerAsync(parameter);
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(parameter.Path);
        var blobRequestOptions = await _blobRequestOptionsManager.GetUploadBlobRequestOptions().ConfigureAwait(false);

        var exists = await blob.ExistsAsync(blobRequestOptions, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (!parameter.Overwrite && exists)
        {
            return false;
        }

        await blob.UploadTextAsync(parameter.InputStream, parameter.Encoding, null, blobRequestOptions, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        return true;
    }

    public async Task<string> DownloadTextAsync(DownloadTextBlobParameter parameter)
    {
        var container = await EnsureBlobContainerAsync(parameter);
        var blob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(parameter.Path);
        var blobRequestOptions = _blobRequestOptionsManager.GetDownloadBlobRequestOptions();

        var exists = await blob.ExistsAsync(blobRequestOptions, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        if (exists)
        {
            return await blob.DownloadTextAsync(parameter.Encoding, null, blobRequestOptions, null).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        return null;
    }
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Just to be sure, you said that uploading/downloading byte streams works.  You've tested that on different machines?  Also, one thing you might want to try is to capture the HTTP traffic (I use Fiddler for this, or Wireshark).  That will help determine if the problem is in the client (the data is being downloaded but not decrypted/returned) or if there's no data at all.